# school-task tag: is this what SO is for?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

I'd like to know, are tags like [school-task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/school-task) good to keep on SO? It seems to me it'd attract "please do my homework"-style questions, and besides, I don't see how this tag would serve any useful purpose like a good tag would.

It's an incredibly broad tag, so there's no further information provided by the use of this tag. You can't really be an expert at "school tasks", and I'd doubt if anybody would ever want to add school tasks to their favourite tags list (what kind of questions would they be expecting?)

So I'd like to request this tag to be deleted, as I don't see any good reason to keep this task, and I do think it might attract more low-quality questions.

PS: is there any other way to flag tags for moderator attention than to create a post here?

Comment: Pretty sure it's just a euphemism for "homework".

Comment: @BoltClock Can I has [meta-tag:status-completed]?

Comment: You can definitely be an expert in "school tasks," but I'm not sure you'd want it to show up on your Careers profile. ;)

Comment: At all, isn't this kind of a meta tag, which aren't welcome to SO anyway?!

Comment: @BilltheLizard I think the point is that "school tasks" is no subject. I may ask you a "school task" on a subject that is not your realm of expertise and thus compeletely unknown to you, and you will fail miserably.

Comment: I could see one use: to add it to the ignore list. But greatly outweighed by the risk of attracting more exercise dumps.

Comment: Reminds me of the ol' `homework`-tag-burn-of-'12: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123758/can-we-now-discourage-the-use-of-and-burninate-the-homework-tag

Comment: And the follow-deprecation of the `homework` tag: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated